# dns-prefetch on multi language site - only shows on one, incorrectly

Tags: i18n-l10n

During an automated search for broken links on our sites I found this faulty line in the `<head>` section in ONE of our sites (out of 8 TLDs running on the same Drupal installation):

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//languages" />
```

The only traces of `dns-prefetch` I can find in the code is in the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg), which also has some admin settings regarding this:

[image: screenshot from AdvAgg dns-prefetch settings]

I tried checking `Preconnect (recommended)`, but that just generated a new faulty line:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="//languages" />
```

Interestingly, when I open the `languages` table in MySQL, the only language that has a value (a 43 character hash/salt string) in the `javascript` column is the same that shows the faulty dns-prefetch value. Coincidence?

The goal is of course to get `dns-prefetch` to work, and to do so on all sites. I'm a bit clueless on where to start though. Is `languages` an array or object that doesn't get printed properly somehow?

SETUP: Drupal 7.58 / PHP 5.4.16 / 5.5.56-MariaDB / Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) / Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation (AdvAgg) 7.x-2.33
(we're planing to upgrade to PHP 7, just not there yet... :-)

**UPDATE:**
The value in the `languages => javascript` DB-column does indeed affect this. The value is printed as a part of a aggregated JS-path. This path has also "//languages" as the initial part of the path, instead of a proper domain or relative path.

Comment: A fix for this is in the latest dev version

Comment: Here's the bug report I posted on drupal.org which lead to the fix mentioned by @mikeytown2: https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/issues/2964646
   
  
(as this question is sorted out, but there has no actual answer - how can I set it as closed/ready?)